# Entity Framework CTP5 Reload related entities

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-ctp5

I am considering whether or not to drop from the EF CTP5 in the development of the new application I just started.

Here's my situation:

```
public class EnergieContext : DbContext, IEnergieContext
{
    public EnergieContext()
        : base("EnergieDatabase")
    {
        this.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;
    }
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<RegionUser>()
            .Property(ru => ru.RegionUserID).HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity);
    }

    public DbSet<Region> Regions { get; set; }
    public DbSet<RegionUser> RegionsUsers { get; set; }

public class Region
{
    public int RegionID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<RegionUser> RegionUsers { get; set; }
}

public class RegionUser
{
    [Key]
    [Column(Order = 0)]
    public int RegionUserID { get; set; }

    [Key]
    [Column(Order = 1)]
    public int RegionID { get; set; }

    [Key]
    [Column(Order = 2)]
    public int ZicyzUserID { get; set; }

    public DateTime? DateAllocated { get; set; }

    public DateTime? DateRemoved { get; set; }

    public bool IsActive { get; set; }

    public virtual Region Region { get; set; }       

    [NotMapped]
    public virtual Employee ZicyzUser { get; set; }
}
```

My goal is to filter out the inactive users, rather than deleting entries from the table I mark the deleted user as inactive, i.e. `IsActive = false;`...

I achieved the filtering like this:

```
public Region GetRegionDetails(int regionID)
    {
        Region region = Regions.Where(r => r.RegionID == regionID).FirstOrDefault();

        Entry(region).Collection(r => r.RegionUsers).Query().Where(ru => ru.IsActive == true).Load();

        return region;
    }
```

This would fill the `RegionUsers` collection with all `RegionUser` entities which are marked with `IsActive = true`. That means that that those marked as inactive are left our from fetching :)

However, if I decide to update any of the `RegionUser` entities with `IsActive = false` the change is reflected in the `RegionUsers` collection but the problem is that the collection still contains the item which I wish to filter out.

I have read that `Entry(Regions).Reload()` should perform a read from the database, unfortunately that does not happen and I still end up stuck with the "Inactive" items that just won't leave :(

Please help :)

Thanks!

Nermin.

Comment: CTP5 is outdated version. You should use EF 4.1RC

Comment: Hi Ladislav, actually I am using 4.1 RC, sorry for misinforming :(

Answer (score 0):

No. `Reload` will load again only main entity but not its navigation properties. Navigation properties are loaded and not affected by reloading the parent.

You can try to do this (not sure if this helps):

```
var inactiveUser = GetInactiveUser(region);
context.Entry(inactiveUser).State = EntityState.Detached;
```

Comment: That's cool but I can't see what it does? I am trying to re-load a navigation property, i.e. the `ICollection`. Initially the navigation property wouldn't filter at all. What I had to do is tell this `this.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;
` to the context's constructor in order to avoid loading unfiltered nav prop initially. Then in my `GetRegionDetails(int regionID)` method I was able to filter, but only the first time :( Perhaps the property `Detached` could play a role with the `ICollection`?!

Comment: I ended up with completely detaching the `ICollection` from the Entity `Region` and loading the collection manually. It's a workaround but I am still seeking for a solution on how to reload the related entities.